# AngularJs issue changing between independent parent views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an issue and I was not able to find it's cause. I'm using Angular and UI-Router.

My app has a public part and a private part (accessible after login). Each has it's own design and structure. So one could say that they are independent from each other.

This is all I have in index.cshtml:

```
<div ui-view="appView"></div>
```

Everything works fine while I am using the public pages.
After login, when I try to change states, a second div gets inserted in the resulted html. So it's like this:

```
<div ui-view="appView" class="ng-scope">...</div>
<div ui-view="appView" class="ng-scope">...</div>
```

where the first div is the container for the private pages and the second div is the container for the public pages. So they are displayed all at the same time.

Any tips or ideas about the cause of this issue would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use just one `ui-view` directive and dont separate in level of `view`s but on level of `states`. For example: `app.public.state1` and `app.authenticated.state2`. The states then have their own templates and controllers and substates. The `app` and `app.public` and `àpp.authenticated` should be declared as abstract states where you canno't enter and use them jsut to build some common UI (like headers, navigation, etc) and also to resovle if user is authenticated / redirect to login etc...